# Absolute and Relative paths in Javascript and MathJax

Tags: javascript, ios, path, mathjax

I am trying to set up MathJax on iOS and am setting up the MathJax src file. In the tag where it asks for the source I think that it wants the relative path, but all of my html files are imbedded within folders. I want to access just one MathJax source file though, not imbed it within all of my folders. it is like this

- MathJax.js (NEED TO ACCESS THIS)
- folder 1

  - subFolder1

    - html file1
  - subfolder2

    - html file 2
- folder 2

  - subFolder3

    - html file 3

`<script type="text/javascript" src="MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>`

Is there a way to specify an absolute path for the src, or get it to access a file several levels up? Thank you!

Comment: This is more of an `HTML` question...but just use src="../../MathJaz.js" (according to the example provided)